# Capture new line in a string

Tags: php, html

I know for sure that this was already been asked before but I just googled around and couldn't find anything (maybe wrong word choice?).
Just don't be too mad at me, I'm getting mad too...

I'd like

```
$string = '
This is a line
This is another line
';
```

to be shown to the HTML page as

```
This is a line
This is another line
```

when I do `echo $string;`.
How can I capture the return key or the new line and replace it with `<br>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/nl2br) function:

```
echo nl2br($string);
```

Would return:

```
<br>
This is a line<br>
This is another line<br>
```

To trim off the leading and trailing new lines, use [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim):

```
echo nl2br(trim($string));
```

Would return:

```
This is a line<br>
This is another line
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP function [nl2br](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php). It doesn't *replace* the newlines but, rather, inserts `<br />` next to them (which is perfectly fine for your purposes).

Using your example:

```
$string = '
This is a line
This is another line
';
echo nl2br($string);

/* output
<br />
This is a line<br />
This is another line<br />
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nl2br` function like this:

```
echo nl2br($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting it with nl2br, your new line character must not be \n.

```
print nl2br( str_replace( array( "\r\n", "\r" ), "\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
$string = "
This is a line\n
This is another line
";
```

?
 or use

```
$string = <<<EOF
    This is a line
    This is another line
EOF;
```